# Javascript validation inside a loop function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Hello fellow more experienced javascript sufferers :)

i'm building a form but i have problems with my custom validation.

For you to test the form:
https://pro.formview.io/#/iisqnchhqsvcpgy/validationlooptest

I made it with form.io...

In this form the user selects a task, an action and a commodity(goods) and adds it to a table(changes_EditGrid).
The validation displays the error message (valid = "The selection has been already assigned.";) as soon the user chooses to have the same combinations of task, action and goods multiple times inside the table.

**Validation:**

```
if (Array.isArray(data.changes_EditGrid)) {
    let assigned = data.changes_EditGrid;
    for (var i = 0; i < assigned.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < assigned.length; j++) {
            if (i === j) {
                continue;
            }
            let tasks1 = assigned[i].editGrid_Tasks_Select;
            let tasks2 = assigned[j].editGrid_Tasks_Select;

            let goods1 = assigned[i].editGrid_Goods_Select;
            let goods2 = assigned[j].editGrid_Goods_Select;

            let action1 = assigned[i].editGrid_Actions_Select;
            let action2 = assigned[j].editGrid_Actions_Select;

            if (tasks1 == tasks2) {
                if (goods1 == goods2) {
                    if (action1 == action2) {
                        valid = "The selection has been already assigned.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TASK:** Now i want to exclude 'other goods' (label) (value: 4) which is inside 'editGrid_Goods_Select' from the validation loop shown above.
So that there is no validation for any combination with multiple "other goods".

Further explanation:

- 'data.changes_EditGrid' is an array
- editGrid_Goods_Select, editGrid_Actions_Select and editGrid_Tasks_Select each have the values from 0 to 2, 3 or 4 (JSON for editGrid_Goods_Select is right below)
- there is an invisible 'on-any-click-loop' around the validation code

```
"label": "editGrid_Goods_Select",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "steel",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "label": "wood",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "label": "plastic",
        "value": "2"
      },
      {
        "label": "glas",
        "value": "3"
      },
      {
        "label": "other",
        "value": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I already tried to make a function for the new loop for 'goods', but the framework seems to kick me out of the loop as soon i use a return statement. But actually i have no idea why it's not working.

Please help me.

Comment: What do `goods1` and `goods2` variables contain exactly? a value aka "0", "1" and so on, or label "steel", "glass"?

Comment: ```           console.log(goods1);  ---------> 0 to 4
            console.log(goods2);   ----------> 0 to 4
            console.log(typeof goods1); ---> number (The number type represents both integer and floating point numbers in js.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what type of data `goods1` and `goods2` contain, so let's assume they contain a value "0" or "3" etc.

With this in mind we can simply check if these variables contain "other" value "4" and if so, skip the check and continue the loop:

```
if (goods1 == "4" || goods2 == "4")
  continue;
```

This can also be integrated into the rest of conditions:

```
            if (goods1 != "4" &&
                goods2 != "4" &&
                tasks1 == tasks2 &&
                goods1 == goods2 &&
                action1 == action2)
            {
              valid = "The selection has been already assigned.";
            }
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you man! I tried it like this in this code and in my main program and it works! I can't believe it was actually that easy, i struggle so much. I have to learn ALOT i guess.